# connecting oracle database with MS Excel

Tags: excel, oracle, odbc

I am creating connection of excel spread sheets with my oracle database. But, tnsnames.ora cannot read in ODBC data sources. I have already created an environmental variable of tnsnames.ora but still its not working. 
path: C:\OraCient12c\Administrator\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin

I am using Windows Server 2012R2.

Below image showing the problem. 
[image]

Comment: Please show error message?

Comment: kindly check the edits.

Comment: Is your Excel 64 bit?

Comment: Is your Oracle Client also 32 bit?

Comment: "tnsnames.ora cannot read in ODBC data sources".  Of course not.  tnsnames is just a reference file. It is read by the oracle client. It doesn' read anything. The odbc diver reads tnsnames.ora.  "an environmental variable of tnsnames.ora"  What did you name the environment variable and how do you expect it to be used?  Your image doesn't show any problem. It simply shows and ODBC DSN definition for which you haven't yet supplied the Net Service Name that is referenced in your tnsnames.ora file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the Oracle client connection working independently of ODBC before you go further.

Go to the command/DOS prompt and then use `TNSPING database-name` to check that the Windows client can make a connection to Oracle (`database-name` is whatever the Oracle database you're working with is called).

If TNSPING can't run at all, you need to install Oracle client.

If TNSPING runs but can't locate/ping your database, proceed to set up TNSNAMES.ora until you get it to see the database.

To point to the correct location for your own TNSNAMES.ora, use the Windows environment variable TNS_ADMIN (http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_windows_TNS_ADMIN_environment_variable.htm).

Set up the content of TNSNAMES.ora with the network locations of whatever particular databases you want to work with.

Once your Oracle client configuration is correct, then you can proceed to set up ODBC data source. Put your database name as the TNS service name, and an Oracle user in the User ID field. Hopefully it will connect using the ODBC layer.